# Stacking WPF Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written a little WPF window which starts on the bottom right.

This is how I set the position:

```cs
Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width - 2;
Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - Height - 2;
```

Now when I start the window several times, the window starts in front of the other windows.
How can I stack them on Top of each other so nothing is hidden?

Comment: A possible approach might be to save the position of last shown window in a file that will be shared among all your app instances. Before opening the Window you have to read from file the last shown window position and set the Left and Top of the new window accordingly. Remind to handle file access concurrency.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I just solved it with that aproach

Comment: glad to know that. You may upvote my comment then :)